# Handle filesUpload in a single table Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, doctrine

Thank you for your interest,

## SHORT

I want to manage all my uploads (Image, PDF, Video etc...) in a single entity, so I use entity Inheritance to get various "types" and OneToOne relations to link parent entity with correct upload. I didn't found any bundle to do this and face problems:

- Constraints use
- Setting uploaded file and not upload entity
- Get uploaded file and not upload entity (edition)

## LONG

Instead of having 1 file management in each table (which is quiet verbose) I preferred to have only one table `Uploads` to handle every Uploads. Then I just have to do OneToOne relations to get my file, plus using inheritance I can apply various treatment depending on `Image` or `PDF` for example.

I have at least 4 entities that needs image, so I think that 1to1 relation is a good choice.

But I face problems doing things like this :

- `Constraints` aren't taking into account
- Edition of `$file` should set `$file->file` (it doesn't send the entity from `Uploads`/`Image` but the file to create this entity
- The Uploaded file isn't loaded on entity edition and should be reuploaded each time I edit entity

Does anyone did this ? I can't find out how to achieve this correctly.

Looking at the assert problem I tried to:

- Define asserts on `Image` (this doesn't work as expected as the form target the `$file` of `WithImage`)

  - Using annotation `@Assert\Image()`
  - Using `loadValidatorMetadata`
  - Using annotation `@Assert\Callback()`
- Define assert on form field `'constraints' => array(new Assert\Image())`, this works but need to be defined everywhere I use it...

Looking at the setter misused I found a workaround, but this is quiet ugly:

```
public function setFile($file = null)
{
    if ($file instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) {
        $tmpfile = new Image();
        $tmpfile->setFile($file);
        $file = $tmpfile;
    }
    $this->file = $file;

    return $this;
}
```

(PS: I read about traits to avoid copy/paste of code, I have checked the SonataMediaBundle but this doesn't seems to apply to my case)

## CODE

So I designed my classes as follow:

<kbd>Entity\Uploads.php</kbd> To handle all the life of a file from upload to remove (and access, move, edit, possibly thumbnail etc ...)

```
<?php

namespace Acme\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

use Acme\CoreBundle\Utils\UUID;

/**
 * Uploads
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="uploads")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\CoreBundle\Repository\UploadsRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="class", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"image" = "Image"})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
abstract class Uploads
{
    protected $file;

    private $tempFileName;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fileName", type="string", length=36, unique=true)
     */
    private $fileName; // UUID

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="extension", type="string", length=4)
     */
    private $extension;


    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set date.
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return uploads
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set fileName.
     *
     * @param string $fileName
     *
     * @return uploads
     */
    public function setFileName($fileName)
    {
        $this->fileName = $fileName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fileName.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFileName()
    {
        return $this->fileName;
    }

    /**
     * Set extension
     *
     * @param string $extension
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function setExtension($extension)
    {
        $this->extension = $extension;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get extension
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExtension()
    {
        return $this->extension;
    }

    public function getFileNameExt()
    {
        return $this->getFileName().'.'.$this->getExtension();
    }

    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        if (null !== $this->getId()) {
            $this->tempFileName = $this->getFileNameExt();
            $this->fileName = null;
            $this->extension = null;
        }
    }

    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
    * @ORM\PrePersist()
    * @ORM\PreUpdate()
    */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }
        $this->extension = $this->file->guessExtension();
        $this->fileName = UUID::v4();
        $this->preUpdateFile();
    }

    protected function preUpdateFile(){} // To define if specific treatment

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function prePersistDate()
    {
        $this->date = new \DateTime();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @ORM\PostPersist()
    * @ORM\PostUpdate()
    */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        if (null !== $this->tempFileName) {
            $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().$this->tempFileName;
            if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
                unlink($oldFile);
            }
        }

        $this->file = $this->file->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->getFileNameExt()
        );

        $this->postUpdateFile();
    }

    protected function postUpdateFile(){} // To define if specific treatment

    /**
    * @ORM\PreRemove()
    */
    public function preRemoveUpload()
    {
        // On sauvegarde temporairement le nom du fichier
        $this->tempFileName = $this->getFileNameExt();
        $this->preRemoveFile();
    }

    protected function preRemoveFile(){} // To define if specific treatment

    /**
    * @ORM\PostRemove()
    */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().$this->tempFileName;
        if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
            unlink($oldFile);
        }
        $this->postRemoveFile();
    }

    protected function postRemoveFile(){} // To define if specific treatment

    public function getFileUri()
    {
        return $this->getUploadDir().$this->getFileNameExt();
    }

    public function getUploadDir()
    {
        return 'uploads/';
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getFileNameExt();
    }
}
```

<kbd>Entity\Image.php</kbd> A specific type of upload with its own constraints and file management

```
<?php

namespace Acme\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\CoreBundle\Repository\ImageRepository")
 */
class Image extends Uploads
{
}
```

<kbd>Entity\WithImage.php</kbd> An entity which needs an `Image`

```
<?php

namespace Acme\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * WithImage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="with_image")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\CoreBundle\Repository\WithImageRepository")
 */
class WithImage
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts come to my mind to help you achieve what you want.

First, you have to upload the files in a form, and the constraints should be in a property in an entity (unless you want to have the pain of writing your constraints in every form, which is not very mantainable). So, for every entity that's going to have files, define a file property (not ORM anotated) and write your constraints there. Also add the respective getters and setters.

```
/**                                                                         
 * @var UploadedFile                                                        
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"New"})                                         
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={"text/html", "text/markdown", "text/plain"})     
 */                                                                         
private $file;
```

Second, you might ask ¿but how do I save them to a different Entity? This is when I would recommend you to use a Doctrine Event Subscriber. Basically, is a service that is defined with a `doctrine.event_subscriber` tag which class implements the `Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber` Interface. You can subscribe to events like `preUpdate`, `postLoad`, and the interesting for you: `prePersist`.

My take on this would be that you subscribe to the `prePersist` event. The event will pass you the entity (with that file non-orm property we created, that has the `UploadedFile` instance holding your file info).

Then, using the info for that file, create a new Upload entity, pass all the info you want, and then set that in the real file orm mapped property that holds your file relationship with your desired entity. For this to work you will have to enable persist cascade if I recall correctly.

The benefits of this:
1. You can define your constraints in your Entities.
2. You can have the Uploads Entity you desire.

The only major problem is that you will have to do all the retrieval, storing and updating of the Uploads entity through a listener. But's the only thing I can think of to help you.

Comment: Never heard about doctrine event subscriber, will try this thanks :)